# Probability contradiction

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose we flip a coin $n$ times $n \geq 1$. The probability of getting one of $H,TH,HT,... = \{\text{set of all possible coin tosses}\}$ is $1$. Then see that the probability of getting $H,TH,TTH,\ldots$ where we add $1$ tails to the left at each step is also $1$ ($\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{4}+\cdots = 1)$ but we are leaving out cases such as $HT,HHT,$ etc. Isn't this a contradiction? How can this be possible?

Comment: But the probability to get the first tail is $1/2$. Thus the probability of getting H,TH,TTH,… where we add 1tails to the left at each step is  $1
/2 (1/2+1/4+⋯=1)=1/2$.

Comment: @wece I don't get what you mean by "the probability to get the first tail is $1/2$" and how that affects  my probability.

Comment: Sorry, what is the event space here?  All possible sequences of tosses where the length of the sequence is also unknown? What is the probability distribution of the length?

Comment: If we have our sample space as "Flip until we see the first head" then your calculation and sample space $\{H,TH,TTH,TTTH,\dots\}$ is correct.  We are (*almost*) guaranteed to see a first head eventually occur (with probability $1$).  The cases such as $HT$ and $HHT$ are seen as sub-cases of the case $H$.  If we stop recording the flips after the first head occurs, additional heads are certainly able to occur after it.

Comment: @JMoravitz I'm still confused. Both probabilities are $1$, right?

Comment: If as lulu suggests, you are looking at the sample space being all finite-length sequences of coin flips, then the probability of getting a result such as $H$ is *not* $\frac{1}{2}$ but rather $Pr(\text{sequence length is 1})\cdot \frac{1}{2}$.  Similarly for all other calculated probabilities above.  Compare this to $Pr(\text{first toss is heads}) = \frac{1}{2}$ which includes *all* outcomes such as $\{H,HH,HT,HHH,HHT,HTH,HTT,HHHH,\dots\}$ where the first toss is a head.

Comment: It makes no obvious sense to say "both probabilities are $1$" unless you specify the event space.  If I have sequences of length $1$ then the list $\{H,T\}$ has probability $1$.  If I have length $2$ then the list $\{HH, HT, TH, TT\}$ has probability $1$.  No contradiction, just different event spaces.

Comment: @lulu I am looking at every positive integer $n$ I don't know how else to define it.

Comment: Fine, but then you need to specify the probability of getting a specific length.  Take my example (only lengths $1$ or $2$ allowed).  You can't just "add them up".  That would be probability $2$. You could say $\frac 12$ for each if you wanted to.  But then $H$ would have probability $\frac 14$ and $HH$ would have probability $\frac 18$.

Comment: You overcount things: the one-half in your summation is the probability of the whole set of words {Hw | w of length n-1}, with size 2^(n-1), likewise one-fourth stands for the probability of {THw | w of length n-2}, with size 2^(n-2), until one adds twice 1/2^n, once for the unique word T^(n-1)H and once for the unique word T^n.

Comment: @Puzzled417  You can see from the comments here, and the comments attached to my posted solution, that there are at least two ways to interpret your question.  Both are rational, but presumably you only intended one of them (at most).  do either of these interpretations address your concern?

Answer (score 1):

To be clear at least about where the confusion lies:  It appears that the event space in question is $$\Omega =\{\text {All possible finite binary sequences} \}$$

the difficulty, then, is that it is not at all obvious what probability measure one wants to attach to that.  It is certainly not sensible to suggest that $p(H)=\frac 12,\;P(HH)=\frac 14$ and so on.  After all, the events $\{H,T, HH\}$ would already have combined probability exceeding $1$.

The most natural way to proceed, I think, would be to declare a probability for each possible length.  Thus we'd need a sequence of non-negative numbers $\{a_i\}$ such that $\sum a_i=1$.  Clearly no uniform distribution is possible here (no constant sequence $\{a_i\}$ could sum to $1$).  until that probability is declared it doesn't make sense to speak of probabilities within $\Omega$.

Comment: Ingenious, but unrelated to the problem.

Comment: @Did  How so?  In the comments, I thought the OP was quite clear that this was the question being addressed.

Comment: Trivially so, because the set Omega you suggest does not model n throws of a dice. The OP explains they fix n once and for all then consider the set of the 2^n sequences of n results.

Comment: @Did  the OP clearly states "I am looking at every positive integer n I don't know how else to define it".  If a single length $>1$  is fixed, then what does the event $H$ mean?  Well, let's hear from the OP.  If my post is off the mark, I'll gladly delete it.

Comment: "If a single length >1 is fixed, then what does the event H mean?" Exactly the source of the OP's confusion, according to their post.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, you can't just add a tails in front of every combination without changing the probability. Think of a simple case with $n = 2.$ Our sample set is ${HH, HT, TH, TT}.$ If we add a tails in front, our sample space becomes **larger;** now we have a sample space with $2^{3} = 8$ elements. Notice that only $4$ of those $8$ begin with tails (the equivalent of adding a tail in front of a smaller set of coins). So the probability is not $1,$ but $\frac{1}{2}.$ Hopefully this also makes some intuitive sense.